# cómo resetear e inhabilitar un input y un select al seleccionar un elemento de otro select?

Tags: php, javascript, html, select

Se que la pregunta no está del todo formulada pero estoy teniendo problemas al querer configurar un select:

el objetivo es el siguiente 
 yo tengo un select el cual tiene:

**Forma de entrega**:

- Elegir...
- Por Oficina
- Por depósito Bancário

la idea es que al usar el **select** y seleccionar el **option** por ejemplo de **oficina** éste haga aparecer otro **select** a su costado donde en ese **select** ya tenga los elementos de:

- Seleccionar
- Oficina A
- Oficina B
- Oficina C

si se selecciona **Depósito Bancário** éste haga que desaparesca el **select** de oficinas y solo aparezca un simple **input** que acepte números:

**Ingresar Numero de Cuenta:** 000.0000.000.0000

con estas acciones quiero que al seleccionar por ejemplo **oficina**: limpie o resetee los datos dentro del input y si se selecciona depósito bancario éste regrese a la posicion del otro select a **Seleccionar**

Soy Novato en desarrollo web, de antemano agradezco la ayuda :D
Dejaré el codigo que he estado realizando, la parte de aparecer y desaparecer los elementos ya los he hecho ahora solo quiero que las acciones sean borradas para que dentro de la BD no se envien ambos datos de los elementos sino mas que solo 1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
<form action="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <br>
            <div class="form-row">

                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <STRONG><font size="5px">Transacción :</font></STRONG><br><br>
                <div class="input-group">


                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Forma de Entrega :</span>
                      </div>
                    <select class="custom-select" name="SelectOptions" id="SelectOptions" required="">
                        <option disabled="disabled" value="" selected>Elegir...</option>
                        <option value="Div1">Por Oficina</option>
                        <option value="Div2">Depósito Cuenta Bancária</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-0.5"></div>

                 <div class="DivPai">
                    <div class="Div1">
                        <STRONG><font size="5px"></font></STRONG><br><br>
                        <select class="custom-select">
                            <option disabled="disabled" selected value="">Elegir nombre de Oficina</option>
                                <option value="1">Oficina A</option>
                                <option value="2">Oficina B</option>
                                <option value="2">Oficina C</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Div2">
                        <STRONG><font size="5px"></font></STRONG><br><br>
                         <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="N° de Cuenta del Beneficiario" >
                    </div>

                </div>

                    </form>


            </div>
        </div>
```

.Div1,.Div2,.Div3{display:none;}

```
 <script type="text/javascript">//Funções após a leitura do documento
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Select para mostrar e esconder divs
    $('#SelectOptions').on('change',function(){
        var SelectValue='.'+$(this).val();
        $('.DivPai div').hide();
        $(SelectValue).toggle();
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Pensé que estaba entendiendo lo que querías hacer, pero esta afirmación final no se entiende: *con estas acciones quiero que al seleccionar por ejemplo oficina: **limpie o resetee los datos dentro del input** y si se selecciona depósito bancario éste **regrese a la posicion del otro select a Seleccionar*** ¿?

Comment: Mil disculpas si no me expliqué bien, lo que trato de hacer es que si una persona maneja el select y selecciona ingresar numero de cuenta y escribe algo, y despues cambia de opinión y ahora selecciona oficinas entonces los datos del input text de nuemro de cuenta, quedan escritos aún, mi idea era que sea reseteado para que no quede el campo en uso. y solo se use el otro select para que luego al apretar enviar solo se envie una accion de alguno de esos 2 elementos, es por eso que me apoyo del primer select.